# WSO2 Ballerina natively run into the Carbon server of the EI instance? Some doubts

Tags: wso2, integration, ballerina, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in WSO2 evnironment and I have the following doubt.

I am working using WSO2 ESB\DSS on a WSO2 EI 6.1.1 environment.

Now I am pretty interested into **Ballerina** languange and I have the following doubt:

1. Ballernina natively run into the Carbon server of my EI instance? Or have I to install\configure something else?
2. Can I use Ballerina to develop API (at the moment I am using ESB to develop API but in some case I prefer use something more similar to a proper programming language instead write ESB flow).
3. From Ballerina can I easily call DSS service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ballerina is a programing language designed to solve integration problems. It has built in connectors and components to support common integration patterns.

1. It has own run time where you can just run ballerina services on its own. No need to run on top of Carbon or EI.
2. Yes, its designed to be integration simple, so you can write Endpoints easier a than a regular programing language. Since its a program language it will be more agile than any integration product with configurations.
3. Yes you can. Ballerina provides connectors invoke any service, so you can call DSS. On a separate note, you can write a data service from Ballerina itself without having to use DSS.